# How to find length of a filename?

Tags: c

I wished to find maximum length of filename from a given set of filenames and was using the following code for the purpose:

```
int Max_FnLen=strlen(files[0]->d_name);
for (i=1;i<count-1;i++)
{
if(strlen(files[i]->d_name)>strlen(files[i-1]->d_name))
 { 
   Max_FnLen=strlen(files[i]->d_name);
 }
}
```

But it is not giving the desired output can anyone help me with this

Thank You!

Comment: Why is your loop condition `i < count - 1`? If your array `files` has `count` entries, the loop should be `for (i = 1; i < count; i++) ...`

Comment: As you explicitly use the term "filename", not just string: What is your "desired output" and what do you get instead? What is your input? What does the debugger tell? How are the variables declared? … Read [ask] and provide the required information plus a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int Max_FnLen=strlen(files[0]->d_name);
for (i=1;i<count;i++)
{
if(strlen(files[i]->d_name)>Max_FnLen)
 { 
   Max_FnLen=strlen(files[i]->d_name);
 }
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score -1):

After initially setting the element with the index 0 as the element with the maximum length you should compare the length of each next element with the current value of the maximum length.

The code can look the following way

```
size_t Max_FnLen = strlen( files[0]->d_name );

for ( size_t i = 1; i < count; i++ )
{
    size_t FnLen = strlen( file[i]->d_name );

    if ( Max_FnLen < FnLen )
    {
        Max_FnLen = FnLen;
    }    
}
```

If you need to know also the index of the element with the maximum length then the code can be modified the following way

```
size_t Max_FnLen = strlen( files[0]->d_name );
size_t Max_Index = 0;

for ( size_t i = 1; i < count; i++ )
{
    size_t FnLen = strlen( file[i]->d_name );

    if ( Max_FnLen < FnLen )
    {
        Max_FnLen = FnLen;
        Max_Index = i;
    }    
}
```